# array of char to string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string that looks like a phone number. I'm using a lambda to extract an array of char. Then I want to convert this array into a string. This is what I have:

```
PhoneCandidate = "(123)-321-1234"; //this is just an example of what it could look like
var p = PhoneCandidate.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();

string PhoneNumber = p.toString();
```

However, when I run this code, the variable PhoneNumber becomes just "System.Char[]" instead of the values inside the array.

What do I need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but you could change your Where to a method group: `PhoneCandidate.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()`

Comment: does this change make it any faster to run?

Comment: Nope, gets compiled to the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`string` constructor that takes a `char[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx).

```
string PhoneNumber = new string(p);
```

Comment: Would this execute faster or not? string PhoneNumber = new string(PhoneCandidate.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

Comment: @frenchie: That will compile to identical IL.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this clarification. Probably better to leave it as for  future clarity then.

Answer (score 3):

```
string phone = new string(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331869%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `res = new string(yourArray);`

Answer (score 2):

One of the [`string` constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string.aspx) takes a `char[]`:

```
string PhoneNumber = new string(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this a whole new direction:

```
Dim digits as New Regex(@"\d");
string  phoneNumber = digits.Replace(PhoneCandidate, "");
```

Comment: Which do you think is faster? A regex or a linq expression?

Comment: @frenchie You should **measure** based on real data and volume, but I would expect the Regex to do a lot better here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p` is a `char[]` you can use the following:

```
String phoneNumber = new String(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the best bet is to use the string constructor per (@Adam Robinson) however as an alternative, you can also use `string.Join(string separator,params string[] value)`
([MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx))

```
PhoneCandidate = "(123)-321-1234"; //this is just an example of what it could look like
var p = PhoneCandidate.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();

string str = string.Join(string.Empty,p);
```